# Is there a way to speed up CatBoost.cv on GPU?

Tags: python, catboost

Although CatBoostClassifier is quite fast for me, I'm having very slow performance with `catboost.cv` on GPU.

All all the iterations are quite fast, however every 300-400 iterations, there is a big pause (~5 minutes). Once the pause is over, the iterations continue for about 5 seconds before the next big pause.

I assume catboost.cv is inefficiently passing data to the GPU during these pauses.

During that time, GPU usage ranges from 1% to 20%.

Is there a way to speed up `cv` with GPU? Maybe there is a way to store the whole dataset in GPU so that these pauses no longer happen?

Here is a part of my code that causes the slow down:

```py
from catboost import cv, Pool

params = { 'loss_function': 'MultiClass','task_type':"GPU", 'devices': '0'}

cv_dataset = Pool(data= X_train[features], label= y_train, cat_features=categorical_feature)

scores = cv(cv_dataset, params, fold_count=3, iterations = 1500)
```